# How to get ParticleSystem to be drawn in a pass with its parent node and its depth? (SCNTechnique+Metal)

Tags: xcode, shader, scenekit, arkit, metal

I have a SCNNode and it has particles (SCNParticleSystem) attached to it as a child node.

And I'm using SCNTechnique with multiple passes to create some individual effects, with things like "excludeCategoryMask" and "includeCategoryMask" for some passes.

The problem for me is that i realized the particles are not drawn as part of the node. It's drawn with anything it's in front of.

Example:

**NodeA** is emitting particles *(has a particle emitter as a child)* and NodeA is **excluded** (*excludeCategoryMask*) from **backgroundScene_pass** and **NodeB_pass**:

1. Particle pixel is in front of background outside of its parent NodeA emitting it: **Particle is drawn in front of backgroundScene pixel**;
2. Particle pixel is in front of another node (NodeB) outside of its parent NodeA emitting it: **Particle is drawn in front of NodeB pixel**;
3. Particle pixel is in front of NodeA: **Particle is drawn in front of NodeA pixel**;

I know that because i have individual passes for **backgroundScene_pass**, **NodeA_pass** and **NodeB_pass**;

*(It doesn't matter why. I have my reasons)*

It means there's no depth for the Particles, because since they're a child from NodeA, i thought (and i need it) that **NodeA_pass** depth and colors contains all the particles, including the ones outside of the NodeA's geometry (which has depth) itself.

But that's not the case.

I NEED one of these:

- The **entire particles to be drawn in** the pass with its parent NodeA in the **NodeA_pass** **with its color and depth**;
  or
- The entire particles to be drawn separated in a pass with its own color and depth as output, maybe using something similar we use to drawn individual nodes with ***includeCategoryMask***;

Is it possible? How?

Comment: Nobody has any knowledge on it? I can't believe it..
Only trivial things got responded when it comes to gaming dev?

Comment: unbelievable how nobody knows anything about it "supposedly"